# IntelliJ IDE error java: warnings found and -Werror specified

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3

I am getting below error in IDE `(2020.3.4`) in my java project when I tried to build/Run the project. I am not be able to build/run the application via IDE because of this issue.

```
java: warnings found and -Werror specified
```

[image]
I got below line in my POM file and tried to comment that as well. But same error.

```
                    <configuration>
                        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                        <compilerArgs>
<!--                            <arg>-Werror</arg>-->
                            <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>  <!--or <release>10</release>-->
                    </configuration>
```

Is this any setting specific error.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue, which I fixed by removing `Werror` flag from Intellij:

```
file > settings > Build, Execution Deployment > Java Compiler
```

At the bottom, you can find it under `Override compiler parameter` from there you can remove the option by clicking on `-` button

Also, verify if you are passing this flag to the `maven-compiler-plugin` and remove it if it is not needed.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-Werror</arg>
                <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                <arg>-Xlint:-deprecation</arg>
                <arg>-Xlint:-options</arg>
                <arg>-Xlint:-processing</arg>
                <arg>-Xlint:-serial</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I don't see it in IntelliJ under `Java Compiler - Override compiler parameter ` ONLY modules listed there.

Answer (score 1):

> I got below line in my POM file and tried to comment that as well. But same error.

Make sure you have removed this flag from all possible places in pom.xml files and invoked **Reload** action in the Maven tool window.

Comment: "invalidate Caches /Restart" did the trick. I tried this before. But not sure how it fixed all of sudden.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for `-Werror` and was getting no results back.
In a different form it can be without `-` as a tag in maven-compiler-plugin, example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArguments combine.children="append">
            <Werror />
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Commenting out this piece helped.